# Use template argument's implementation if available, default otherwise

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a `Frontend` template class for different `Controller`s. The `Frontend` should use a `Controller`'s implementation of a method if it is available (i.e. a feature is supported), and a default one otherwise, as in

```
template <typename Controller>
class Frontend
{
  public:
    something()
    {
      // use Controller::something() if possible
      // else use default implementation
    }
};
```

- `Frontend` will use type traits internally to find out more about `Controller`,
- it should not be required for `Controller` to derive from any base class that provides default implementations, because the default method implementations will need information private to `Frontend`.

There will be about 20 methods that might be implemented in `Controller`. I've tried to create (nested) traits that provide information about provided implementations:

```
// (T: Controller class)
T::supportsFeature<FeatureClass, ...>::type
```

So `Controller::supportsFeature<>` must be provided to inform about specific implementations. The `::type` is `std::true_type` if the controller supports a feature or `std::false_type` if it doesn't. I've created a default struct for that purpose that disables any features, so the Controller class must explicitly enable any feature it provides. This seemed to be a comfortable way of carrying information from `Controller` to the `Frontend`, but it has two major drawbacks:

1. It's hard for others (who will eventually provide the `Controller`) to implement `supportsFeature`, because a specialization of a nested traits class must be written
2. I'm not sure how I should evaulate the existence of a feature in `Frontend::something()`, as no argument depends on the existence of that feature - I cannot provide an overload that is reasonably expressive (I don't want to overload for `std::true_type` vs `std::false_type`, because that simply doesn't speak for itself). I could simply use an if-statement and rely on compiler to remove dead code. Should I?

So, to sum it up:

- How do I carry information about the existence of a method from a template class argument to the template class?
- How do I properly switch between implementations, based on that information?

Comment: Use an *SFINAE* check to test whether the given type supports a function (i.e. feature) and then fail to default. Search for that term here if you are not familiar, there are quite a few questions on it..

Comment: You can check out [Boost.TTI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/tti/doc/html/index.html), especially [member function introspection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_member_function.html)

Comment: @Angew Unfortunately, I've had serious problems with boost in this specific environment (embedded) because some macros are polluting boost template argument names. But I should at least try.

Comment: @Christoph You can always copy-paste-edit that part of Boost into your code directly; once you grasp the idea of SFINAE, it's just an excercise of getting the details right.

Comment: @Christoph: how do you represent feature? is it a method, a tag or what ?

Comment: @PiotrS. `Controller::something()` would be a feature provided by `Controller`. `Controller` also provides a struct that informs `Frontend` about the existence of this feature, as in the small code snippet above the enumeration in my question (`T::supportsFeature<>...`). Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use that to check exact signature:

```
#include <cstdint>

#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static std::uint8_t check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);               \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t); \
    }

DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_something, T::something, void (T::*)());
```

then use SFINAE (something like):

```
template <typename Controller>
class Frontend
{
public:
    void something()
    {
        somethingT<Controller>();
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<has_something<T>::value>::type
    somethingT()
    {
        controller.something();
    }

    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<!has_something<T>::value>::type
    somethingT()
    {
        // default implementation
    }
};
```

or Tag dispatching (something like):

```
template <typename Controller>
class Frontend
{
public:
    void something()
    {
        something(typename std::conditional<has_something<Controller>::value,
            std::true_type,
            std::false_type>::type());
    }

private:
    void something(std::true_type) { controller.something(); }
    void something(std::false_type) { /* default implementation */ }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use SFINAE with your suggestion, but I've seen something seemingly similar here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19444/Interface-Detection maybe that helps me to understand your suggestion and put it to use

Comment: @Christoph: I have added some samples which may help you.

Comment: I tested your first example and it works well, even with overloads (`something()` and `something(int)`), using a `DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE` for each overload. That's great! There are surely some limitations lurking in the dark, but I guess I'll find out when the time has come.

Answer (score 1):

After some try/error, here's what I'd name an acceptable solution.

Using SFINAE, of course, all deductions about whether to use the Controller's member function or the default function are done at compile time.

The only thing required to the implementers of the Controllers type is to define a type within the controller as `typedef Controller WithSomething;`. It's not hard compared to the traits you mentionned.

---

First declare the `Frontend` template class, and define two template functions for every of your 20 callable functions. Here there are only two `foo` and `bar`.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

template <typename Ctrl>
class Frontend;

template <typename Ctrl>
void call_foo( typename Ctrl::WithFoo & ctrl ) { ctrl.foo(); }

template <typename Ctrl>
void call_foo( Ctrl & ctrl ) { Frontend<Ctrl>::default_foo( ctrl ); }

template <typename Ctrl>
void call_bar( typename Ctrl::WithBar & ctrl ) { ctrl.bar(); }

template <typename Ctrl>
void call_bar( Ctrl & ctrl ) { Frontend<Ctrl>::default_bar( ctrl ); }
```

Then define the `Frontend` function with the callable functions. Here I defined the default implementations as static member, but this can be changed.

```
template <typename Ctrl>
class Frontend
{
public:
    typedef Ctrl controller;

    void foo() { call_foo<Ctrl>( c ); }
    void bar() { call_bar<Ctrl>( c ); }

    static void default_foo( Ctrl & ctrl ) { cout<<"Default foo\n"; }
    static void default_bar( Ctrl & ctrl ) { cout<<"Default bar\n"; }

private:
    Ctrl c;

};
```

In the end, some examples of the `Controller` classes. One that defines both `foo` and `bar`, and two other that defines only one each.

```
struct CtrlFooBar
{
    typedef CtrlFooBar WithFoo;
    typedef CtrlFooBar WithBar;
    void foo() { cout<<"CtrlFB  foo\n"; }
    void bar() { cout<<"CtrlFB  bar\n"; }
};

struct CtrlFoo
{
    typedef CtrlFoo WithFoo;
    void foo() { cout<<"CtrlFoo foo\n"; }
};

struct CtrlBar
{
    typedef CtrlBar WithBar;
    void bar() { cout<<"CtrlBar bar\n"; }
};
```

Using the `Frondtend` with all these classes, and with an `int` works as expected.

```
int main()
{
    Frontend<CtrlFooBar> c2;
    Frontend<CtrlFoo>    cf;
    Frontend<CtrlBar>    cb;
    Frontend<int>        ci;

    c2.foo();
    c2.bar();
    cf.foo();
    cf.bar();
    cb.foo();
    cb.bar();
    ci.foo();
    ci.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

---

**Output**

```
CtrlFB  foo
CtrlFB  bar
CtrlFoo foo
Default bar
Default foo
CtrlBar bar
Default foo
Default bar
```

Comment: Is there no way to move the `call_xxx()` functions into the class? I'd prefer them not to be free functions.

Comment: I guess you could define the `call_xxx()` functions as templated member functions (use another template typename than Ctrl as it is already used for the class template typename.). Why don't you want them as free functions?

Comment: I don't want them as free functions because that would take them away from their "place of action". I would also have to propagate all necessary types for those methods that have arguments.